# Finding the number of ways every student can borrow at most a book (Discrete Mathmatics)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $A= \{S_{1}, S_{2},S_{3},S_{4}\}$ be a set of four students working on a research project and $B= \{b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}, b_{4}\}$ be a set of reference books on reserve on the library for the project. Below are the books that each student wants to borrow.

$S_{1}:\{b_{2}, b_{3}\}$,

$S_{2}:\{b_{1},b_{3}\}$,

$S_{3}:\{b_{1},b_{2},b_{4}\}$,

$S_{4}:\{b_{2}\}$

Every student can borrow at  most one book and every book can be lent to at most one student. Find a lending arrangement that assigns the most number of books.

What I tried:

Representing the above question in the form of a graph, we let $S_{i}$ be the vertex of the graph and $b_{i}$ be the edges connecting the vertex together. So we want to draw the edges such that it can connect the four vertices $S_{i}$.

We start from edges $b_{1}$ and we can see that it connects vertex $S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$. Edge $b_{2}$ will then connect vertex $S_{1}$, $S_{3}$ and $S_{4}$. Edge $b_{3}$ then connects vertex $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$. While edge $b_{4}$ will form a loop around vertex $S_{3}$. Using this information we could then draw a graph to find the lending arrangement. Is my solution correct? Could anyone explain. Thanks.

Comment: Construct a bipartite graph by letting $S_i$ denote the vertices in one partite set and $b_i$ the vertices in another. Let $S_ib_j$ be an edge if student $S_i$ is interested in book $b_j$. Now we want a maximum matching in this graph.

Comment: You can produce $\{x\}$ by typing \{x\} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow Shahab's hint.

We draw a bipartite graph in which the edges connect the students to the books that they request.  [image: possible_assignments_of_books_to_students]

From looking at the graph above, we see that the only way to assign book $b_4$ is to give it to student $S_3$, shown with a blue segment below.  Since a student may only borrow one book, this eliminates the possibility of assigning either book $b_1$ or book $b_3$ to student $S_3$, shown with red segments below.

We can also see from the graph above that student $S_4$ can only be assigned book $b_2$, shown with a blue segment below.  Since only one student may receive a particular book, assigning book $b_2$ to student $S_4$ eliminates the possibility of assigning book $b_2$ to student $S_1$, shown with a red segment in the graph below.

[image: forced_assignments_of_books_to_students]

You want to assign the remaining books so that as many students as possible receive a book they requested.  Can you continue from here?